# Bind custom control property with ListBox.Items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

My custom control has the following basic structure:

```
public class NewTextBox : TextBox
{
    public ItemCollection Items { get; set; }
}
```

And in XAML I have:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" />
<my:NewTextBox Items="{Binding Path=listBox1.Items}" />
```

The bind doesn't work in this case. Is the property `Items` wrong?

Comment: I tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319527/how-to-bind-to-a-custom-property-in-a-silverlight-custom-control) and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880313/bind-wpf-control-with-property-of-custom-type) and it didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding is incorrectly. Use the `ElementName` property in your binding to tell WPF where to look for the data, then bind to the `Items` property

```
<my:NewTextBox Items="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=Items}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Rachel. It works, but I had to modify the property to include the DependencyProperty.